# Headless operations don't work inside Sinatra route

Tags: ruby, selenium, sinatra, headless

I am using the `headless` and `selenium-webdriver` gems to launch a headless Firefox browser:

```rb
headless = Headless.new(
  video: {
    frame_rate: 12,
    codec: 'libx264'
  }
)
headless.start
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox)
```

With this code I can write the following:

```rb
driver.navigate.to("http://google.com")
```

Yet the following raises an error after I visit '/' in the browser:

```rb
get '/' do
  driver.navigate.to("http://google.com")
  erb :root
end
```

The error is as follows:

```
*** Errno::ECONNREFUSED Exception: Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:7055 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 7055)
```

I'm pretty sure this is because the `driver.navigate` is not being called in the headless scope, therefore it can't connect to the Firefox instance.

I have also tried using the modular sinatra style, but the same error occurred.

---

**workaround**

What I ended up doing is separating the headless server in a separate script. This script has `loop` and gets input, printing the output of running the command in the headless scope. Then from the sinatra server, i use `PTY.spawn` to instantiate the server and pass around its stdin and stdout so I can use it in my Sinatra app. This way the headless script is only run once (therefore multiple headless servers aren't started) and I can connect to it from my Sinatra routes. I can't interact with the headless script's variables or methods directly - I need to just use i/o.

I am hoping for an answer which hows how to make the original code work, though (when the sinatra app's routes are called in headless scope)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible trick that can help:

```
this = self
get '/' do
  this.driver.navigate.to("http://google.com")
  erb :root
end
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but I'm not able to connect to my Sinatra server at all when it's running in headless scope. This might be a problem specific to Nitrous, the cloud environment where my code is running. I'll have to try on a different environment.

Comment: :( I will delete this comment within 1 day, then.

Comment: Cool, I did get it working. Didn't need to use the `this = self` trick. What was important was that I start the headless browser only once the sinatra route hit. So I made `start_headless` and `start_driver` methods on a separate class.

Comment: Great! The award here is a bit unfair. I will update the answer with what really helped for the future readers then.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting this working.

At first I thought that what fixed it was doing the headless environment initialization in the scope of a sinatra route, i.e.

`get '/' { do_initialization_here }`

The real fix may have been in the way I was calling `Headless.new` (I originally had a bunch of options tacked on and I removed all them).